# find Date Difference in Milliseconds

Tags: hiveql

I have two fields in hive : forwarddate & recieved date.

forwarddate has values like : 2018-07-18 01:51:30.655 +0200
recieved date has similar values.

I want to find the difference between forwarddate & recieved date in milliseconds

Comment: whats your implementation and the error ?

Comment: I am trying to do something like this :    

select (unix_timestamp(a.auditforwardeddate) - unix_timestamp(a.auditreceiveddate))/60/60/60/1000 as diff_milli  


Result is Zero